# More than one row with the given identifier was found: 1, for class: com.model.Diagnosis

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Below is the model, service implementation and the error trace of my code.

Model class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ph_diagnosis_history")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id",scope=Diagnosis.class)
public class Diagnosis extends AbstractEntity {
    @Column(name = "diagnosis_notes", length=255)
    @Length(max = 255, message = IprProp.MAX_LEN_255_MSG)
    private String diagnosisNote;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private DiagnosisTypeEnum type;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "diagnosis_date")
    @JsonSerialize(using = JsonDateSerializer.class)
    private Date diagnosisDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "patient_chart_id")
    private PatientChart patientChart;

    public String getDiagnosisNote() {
        return diagnosisNote;
    }

    public void setDiagnosisNote(String diagnosisNote) {
        this.diagnosisNote = diagnosisNote;
    }

    public DiagnosisTypeEnum getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(DiagnosisTypeEnum type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Date getDiagnosisDate() {
        return diagnosisDate;
    }

    public void setDiagnosisDate(Date diagnosisDate) {
        this.diagnosisDate = diagnosisDate;
    }

    public PatientChart getPatientChart() {
        return patientChart;
    }

    public void setPatientChart(PatientChart patientChart) {
        this.patientChart = patientChart;
    }
}
```

My service:

```
public Diagnosis updateDiagnosis(IPRDTO clientDto, Long userId,
        Long patientChartId, DiagnosisDTO diagnosisDTO, Long diagnosisId) throws Exception {
    Diagnosis diagnosis = diagnosisRepository.findOne(diagnosisId);
    if (diagnosis!=null){
        if(diagnosis.getType().equals(DiagnosisTypeEnum.WORKING)){
            BeanCopyUtil.copyProperties(diagnosisDTO, diagnosis, true);
            return this.diagnosisRepository.saveAndFlush(diagnosis);
        }
        else{
            throw new BusinessException("updateDiagnosisValidation"); 
        }
    }
    throw new BusinessException("noDiagnosis"); 
}
```

My stack trace:

```
 [2014-09-08 11:34:08,148] INFO  com.zurelsoft.ipr.service.IDiagnosisService- Logged In User Id [1]:Started  updateDiagnosis
    diagnosis id 2
    [2014-09-08 11:34:08,969] INFO  org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener- HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: 2, for class: com.zurelsoft.ipr.model.Diagnosis
    [2014-09-08 11:34:09,001] ERROR com.zurelsoft.ipr.service.IDiagnosisService- Logged In User Id [1]:Error Occurred updateDiagnosis
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: 2, for class: com.zurelsoft.ipr.model.Diagnosis; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: 2, for class: com.zurelsoft.ipr.model.Diagnosis
    [2014-09-08 11:34:09,006] ERROR com.zurelsoft.ipr.client.DiagnosisWebService- org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:321)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403)
    org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:58)
    org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:163)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy85.findOne(Unknown Source)
    com.zurelsoft.ipr.service.impl.DiagnosisServiceImpl.updateDiagnosis(DiagnosisServiceImpl.java:76)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:51)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:51)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:55)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86.updateDiagnosis(Unknown Source)
    com.zurelsoft.ipr.client.DiagnosisWebService.updateDiagnosis(DiagnosisWebService.java:98)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:849)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I get this HibernateException in this line alhough my table has now two rows with the same id.

```
Diagnosis diagnosis = diagnosisRepository.findOne(diagnosisId);
```

Please anyone help me with my mistake. What can be probable error in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Hy, It woks for me:

Seems I have two choices: either cascade all and delete orphan on the one-to-one relationship, or explicitly call my repository class to look up and save the original Sheet every time I remove its relationship with Plate. I opted for the first choice and added this to the plate class:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "plate", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32636186/3255595

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you have more than one row in the database with the same id values!
Are you sure your id is really unique in the DB ?

Hibernate Exception

```
More than one row with the given identifier was found: 2, for class: com.zurelsoft.ipr.model.Diagnosis
```

tells that hibernate query executes returns more than one row (i.e 2) of class **Diagnosis** Please enable SQL logging and execute the select by hand and see what it returns

Answer (score 0):

From Spring documentation:

```
T findOne(ID id)

Retrieves an entity by its id.
```

Seem that diagnosisId is not a primary key.