# org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, hql

org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: 578, for class: com.hibernate.query.performance.persistence.model.Store

The database does not have duplicate Store rows with identifier 578. It was checked using SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM store
WHERE store.store_id = 578;
```

It returned 0 records.

The other questions on [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24210478/hibernate-more-than-one-row-with-the-given-identifier-was-found-error), [Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25718929/more-than-one-row-with-the-given-identifier-was-found-1-for-class-com-model-d) pointed that the issue might be with OneToOne mapping itself. The Store and Staff entities have **OneToOne** relationship and mine are mapped like that:

**Staff:**

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "manager_staff", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    public Store getStore() {
        return store;
    }
```

**Store:**

```
@OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "manager_staff_id", referencedColumnName = "staff_id", nullable = false)
    public Staff getManager_staff() {
        return manager_staff;
    }
```

How to fix it?

---

Update:

The exception changed a bit when the query was modified as:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select c " +
                        " from Rental r, Customer c join fetch c.address address join fetch address.store store join fetch address.city city " +
                        " where r.customer = c " +
                        " and r.returnDate is null");
```

Exception:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: 2951, for class: com.hibernate.query.performance.persistence.model.Store
```

There were no modifications to database. I am not sure if the HQL is correct since JProfiler cannot catch any JPA/Hibernate records. The only metrics being caught is JDBC connections that ran.

Answer (score -1):

Your data is faulty, `OneToOne` means you have to have the link - so make sure the query returns one record. If it needs to be optional you have to make it `OneToMany`